# Access Control regex symfony 2

Tags: regex, symfony, access-control

I need help to configure the access control part of my symfony website.
I want the access for everyone for :

```
/ : the homepage
/login : the login page
/login_check : the check login page for FOSUserBundle
/register : the register page of FOSUserBundle
/resetting/request : the resetting password page of FOSUserBundle
```

And I want the user authenticated for all the rest, for example : /abc, /xxx, /yy/xx ...etc

I put this in security.yml, but it don't work, the user have full access to all in all case :

```
access_control:    
        - { path: /_wdt/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: /_profiler/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: /login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: /login_check, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: /resetting/request, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: /register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: /, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: /*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

What's the problem ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: the problem is that you're missing a period

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that you're missing a period in the last line:

```
      - { path: /*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
              ^^^^^
```

`/*` means zero or more slashes (/) .. .it should be `/.*` to indicate *anything followed by a slash*

Correct entry should be something like:

```
      - { path: /.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Comment: Yes, I correct that, but the main problem is I need to put just before :
- { path: ^/$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

Comment: ACL "regex" is much more simpler. no asterisk and stuff at all.

Answer (score 3):

Strange using of acls. acl regex is much more simpler. `^` marks the beginning of the url. `$` marks the end of the matching url. if no `$` is present, all after the "regex" matches. no asterisk at all. Oh, and login_check should be secured

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }  
    - { path: ^/_wdt, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/_profiler, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```